# Retrieve a document class-description symbolicName without fetching

Tags: vb.net, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I'm triying to retrieve a `ClassDescription` `symbolicName` of an `IDocument` object. It seems that i have to fetch its `ClassDescription` even if I just want the `symbolicName`.

Is there a way to do it ? I just want to avoid doing a fetch for every browsed document...

(Also IDocument.GetClassName doesn't help, it returns "Document")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way, by making an SQL `SELECT` request retrieving the `classDescription` ID (which is not the `symbolicName` ID, but rather an "internal" one) :

```
Select This, d.Id, d.ClassDescription
From Document d
where d.Id = ID
```

It seems to be lighter than a line like `document.fetch(classDescription)` (pseudo call) cause it should just retrieves the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it worth mentioning a problem regarding the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33762470/1677912).

There are times that doing a query would be "lighter" however I believe you are missing something involving fetching a document.

FileNet's fetchInstance command can take in a PropertyFilter.
In your case you could do something along the lines of:

```
PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter();
pf.AddIncludeProperty(new FilterElement(null, null, null, "ClassDescription", null));
doc = Factory.Document.FetchInstance(os, new Id("doc.ID()"), pf);
```

You would probably want to look at your original fetch of this document and make sure to specify the full list of property filters at that point.

See [Working With Documents](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/document_procedures.htm)

Comment: Indeed. Actually I didn't want to perform fetch operations in addition to an SQL request, in order to minimize server calls. I only want fetch properties, ideally in a one-shot, when it's needed (with PropertyFilter as you mentionned it ; I admit it can be an extreme point of view).